# Pass a packed JS file within an asar package to a spawned node child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn, electron

When trying to spawn a node.js `child_process` from within my [electron](/questions/tagged/electron) (previously atom-shell) that runs `node path/to/a/packed/file` I am getting `Cannot find module error` because the path is within the `app.asar` archive (where [asar](https://github.com/atom/asar) is the tar-like archive format).

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\my-app\resources\app.asar\bootstrap\daemon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I understand this is because the unpatched node is trying to locate the `bootstrap/daemon` module within the archive, as though it is a physical file.

Can someone who is more familiar with the asar documentation/code advise a workaround for this?

I have also raised [an issue/question](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2226) for this on the atom/electron GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from [another related issue's comments](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1613#issuecomment-100146829) to add an environment variable of `{ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE : 0}` helped to successfully resolve the issue with using `fork` in place of `spawn`

More details can be seen on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/2226)